# Change Return Value of Class Instance

Tags: python-3.x

How can I overwrite a class with one of its attributes?

e.g.

```
class AListGenerator(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._mylist = [word for word in args if 'a' in word] 
        self = self._mylist # does nothing

>>> x = AListGenerator('mum', 'dad', 'mike', 'aaron')
>>> x
    []

>>> x._mylist
    ['dad', 'aaron']
```

How can I make `x` return `x._mylist`, so that there's no need to call the `_mylist` attribute?

```
 >>> x
     ['dad', 'aaron']
```

To clarify, I do not want/need a `__repr__`, I want to be able to do stuff like:
`x.append('ryan')` and `x` returning `['dad', 'aaron', 'ryan']`, and not just `['ryan']`.

Comment: You already can do `x.append(stuff)` because you're inherenting from `list`.

Comment: @ForceBru True, but I want the values passed to the constructor to be there too (i.e.
` ['dad', 'aaron'] `
)

Comment: @AH, where? Just initiate the base class with `super().__init__(<your list comprehension>)` right at the beginning of `AListGenerator.__init__`.

Comment: @ForceBru You legend, feel free to write that up as the answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inheriting from `list`, so all its methods are already accessible in your class, so you already can do `x.append(stuff)`.

You should (probably always) initiate the base class before doing anything in your `__init__` method:

```
class Stuff(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # initiate the parent class!
        super().__init__(word.lower() for word in args)

        # you also can define your own attributes and methods
        self.random_ID = 5 # chosen by fair dice roll, guaranteed to be random

x = Stuff("HELLO", "WoRlD")
```

And then you can print `x` and do with it everything you can do with a list.